# Find maximum of Gaussian with multiple terms - matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I've got a data set (`x,y`), where I fit a Gaussian with three terms (`gauss3`):

```
[gaussianFit,gof]=fit(x,y,'gauss3');
```

Now, I want to find the maximum of this function. I know that for `gauss1`, the maximum is simply the `b1` parameter, but I have no clue on how to find the maximum, when it is a sum of multiple Gaussians. The terms seems to be weighted (otherwise, my idea was simply an average of the three `b`-terms). My second thought was to solve the entire differentiated function with all the parameters:

```
syms x
diff(a1.*exp(-((x-b1)./c1).^2) + a2.*exp(-((x-b2)./c2).^2) + a3.*exp(-((x-b3)./c3).^2)==0);
solve(dEqn,x)
```

... but this gives me some very weird values for the parameters, which are not the original values. And I feel like this is just a cumbersome solution to something simple.

I hope someone can help me, as I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easiest to reconstruct the distribution from the fitted parameters, but you don't need to use symbolic maths for it.

You can generate the reconstructed curve using `eval`, then find the maximum value of that as normal:

```
a = 3; b = 4; x = 1:10;
recon = eval('a*x + b');
[mx, mI] = max(recon);
```

You can get the expression as a string from the returned fit object, or use the canonical form.